# Как получить число из EditText

Tags: android

Цифра введённая пользователем регулирурет длину будущего пароля.

xml

```
<EditText   
    andriod:id = "@+id/youPasswordLength"
    android:inputType="number"
    />
```

MainActivity.java

```
for(int i = 0; i < youPasswordLength; i ++){  
      int justCaseNumberForRandomChar = randomNumber.nextInt(charForPassword.length);
            passwordHolder.append(charForPassword[justCaseNumberForRandomChar]);
            showPasswordView.setText(passwordHolder.toString());
}
```

Не хочет работать с "youPasswordLength", пробовал через Integer.parseInt результат то-же, подчёркивает красным. Всё что нужно импортировал, переменные везде объявил.   Скажите пожалуста что почитать на эту тему

Comment: Покажите, как вы `youPasswordLength` инициализируете.

Comment: Подчеркивает красным - читай, что пишет.

Comment: `EditText  editText  = findViewById(R.id.youPasswordLength); int passwLength = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText());`

Comment: Эникейщик в том-то и дело, что ни чего не пишет и не предлагает

Comment: Если АС что-то подчёркивает, то всегда написано почему.

Comment: Да, пришет:"Operator '<' cannot be applied to 'int', android.widgiet.EditText" Я дложен "изьять" цифру из EditText, я думал, что она автоматически "ложится" в значение моего EditText-а, как-же её оттуда получить...?

Comment: Ну вот и всё понятно, не правда ли? Выше в комментарии написано как получить.

Comment: да, вы мне очень помогли, спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разобрался, если кому интересно:
 Похоже нельзя напрямую "брать" цифру даже несмотря на то что параметр EditText-a настроен как android:inputType="number"
Для начала я должен перевести данные в стрингу а потом стрингу парсить в цифру...

```
String longOfPass = yourPasswordLegth.getText().toString();// переводим в строку
int longOfPassword_int = Integer.parseInt(longOfPass); // парсим цифру, а дальше                    
                                                      //спокойно работаем с цифрой
```

Comment: ? А при чем тут inputType и тип данных, возвращаемый EditText?
android:inputType="number" отвечает за тип клавиатуры и все,

Comment: Да, это я уже понял, спасибо.